# Brief list of improvements starting from the next Visual Studio edition after 2010 up to the latest 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, visual-studio-2017

So I tried and tried googling about this, but I can't seem to see a list of all the improvements in Visual Studio after **VS2010**. The reason for this is so that I'll be able to recommend our dev team to upgrade hopefully to **VS2017**, but if purchasing budget does not allow it, at least to something newer than 2010 because of course of new features. But I'm not familiar with any aside from the obvious look of the IDE which is now very different from 2010. I'm sure there's already a lot we're missing on the latest VS has to offer. Help will be really appreciated thanks!

Comment: Try searching for "What's new in visual studio 2015" (etc.) and look for the MSDN or Microsoft Docs matches.

Comment: So I was obviously using incorrect keywords. Thanks!

Comment: Biggest selling points are probably: `1` *Greatly* improved load times for large solutions. `2` Binary compatibility of the CRT starting with VS 2015. You can now freely mix libraries compiled with VS 2015, VS 2017, and probably later, too. `3` *Greatly* improved standards compliance, allowing you to use anything introduced in C++11 and up. `4` *Greatly* improved compiler diagnostics. In summary, these allow your team to write safer code, spending less developer time.